# Loop line by line and wall clock time with a Python Filter

Tags: python, filter

I have a simple loop like:

```
#Core Loop
chunk_size=1000
while True:
    line_c = 0 
    chunk_array = []
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        line_c +=1
        m = line_regex.match(line)
        if m:   
            chunk_array.append(m.groupdict())
        if line_c >= chunk_size:
            #print top_value(chunk_array, 'HTTP_HOST', 10)
            print stats(chunk_array, 'HTTP_HAPROXY_TT')
            break
```

The script is called as a unix filter, for example:

```
tail -f /var/log/web/stackoverflow.log | python logFilter.py
```

Instead of printing every X lines, what would be a good way to refactor this loop to do every X seconds?

**Reference:**
Stats function:

```
def stats(l, value):
    '''stats of an integer field'''
    m = []
    for line in l:
        if line[value].isdigit():
            m.append(int(line[value]))
    return "Mean: %s Min: %s Max: %s StdDev: %s" % (mean(m), amin(m), amax(m), std(m))
```

The input will be lines of a web log file, the `line_regex` turns them into field value pairs (`groupdict`). The output when using the stats function is like:

```
tail -f /var/log/web/stackoverflow.log | python logFilter.py -f HTTP_HAPROXY_TR -t stats
Mean: 183.43919598 Min: 0 Max: 3437 StdDev: 321.673112066
Mean: 182.768304915 Min: 0 Max: 2256 StdDev: 255.039386654
Mean: 142.672064777 Min: 0 Max: 1919 StdDev: 208.870675922
```

So those stat lines are printed every time the script has received 1000 lines. Instead of doing it every X number of lines, I would like to change the loop so this happens every say 10 seconds.

Comment: What does do this "every X seconds" mean?  Are you asking about adding a `time.sleep()` or using `cron`?

Comment: @S.Lott: Right now it runs the stat function or top_value function as soon as 1000 lines have been parsed `if line_c >- chunk_size` (or attempted to be parsed I should say). Instead of it doing it every time it gets 1000 lines, I would like to do that every 10 seconds for example. This will be a variable amount of lines depending on how many lines have been passed to the script in that time frame.

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: So you're counting lines as well as elapsed time?  `time.time() - starttime > 10` sort of thing?

Comment: Well I gather X lines of a log. And then run some reports on the lines. For instance the TOP occurring of a client IP for those lines. Basically so I can watch this activity in near real time.

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: I'm stumped.  Please **udpate** your question with some pseudo-code for what it is you're talking about.  It isn't making much sense in little comment-sized dribbles.

Comment: @S.Lott: Updated with some more code, not really sure how to be any more clear though :-/

Comment: @Kyle Brandt: There's a trick to being more clear.  It's called assume less.  Some of us are just utterly baffled by the problem you've been studying and thinking about for a long time.  It helps to fall back to basics -- input, output, loops and if-statements -- to coach the less knowledgable through your specific issue.

Comment: @S.Lott: Oh I am being dense. `time.time() - starttime > 10` is exactly what I wanted. So if you post an answer with replace `if line_c >= chunk_size` with `if time.time() - starttime > 10` then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
import time
def time_chunk( some_source, period=10 ):
    start= time.time()
    buffer= []
    for line in some_source:
        buffer.append( line )
        if time.time() - start >= period:
            start= time.time()
            yield buffer
            buffer= []
    yield buffer

for chunk in time_chunk( sys.stdin ):  
    print( stats( chunk ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

To do something every -- say -- 5 seconds in Python, you can use the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module.  To fire the timer every 5 seconds, use

```
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 5.0, 5.0)
```

and install a handler which is called in this interval by

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
```

where `handler` is the function you want to be called in this interval.